# Merged commits from gerrit to jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins-plugins, gerrit, repo

I am generating an automated mails in Jenkins which gives info about the builds triggered and now I want to put the merged commits(Commit id, Message, Owner) info also from the Gerrit in those mails in the form of a table.
Is there any way to get all the merged commits from gerrit and put them in a mail generated from jenkins or is there any plugin for it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So when a patchset is created for a change/commit a build job is triggered in Jenkins - and that job also generate a mail about the result? And in that mail you want to see which commit belongs to that build?

Comment: yes, only the merged between two successful builds and i am generating my builds on a daily basis. Everyday i generate the build which includes the commits of last 24 hrs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building daily and using the git SCM then each Jenkins build page should list the changes for that build. You can use the "Email-ext" plugin to send a mail for the build. It is extremely configurable and can include the list of changes in the email:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin